# How can I add timezone to Esper queries?

Tags: timezone, timezone-offset, complex-event-processing, esper, timestamp-with-timezone

I am using Esper & I need to filter events by their timestamp. The events come from an external source.

The challenge is that the cutoff instant is at a different timezone than the events` timestamp, e.g. the cutoff instant is at 3:30 CET (e.g. Prague time) while the timestamp field of the event is at UTC.

This poses a problem when the timezone shifts to Daylight Savings Time, because the cutoff instant needs to be modified in the query. E.g. in this case, if the cutoff instant is 3:30 CET, during winter time it would be on 2:30 UTC and during DST it would be on 1:30 UTC. It means that I have to change the query when the time shifts into and out of DST.

This is the current query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   my_table
WHERE  timestamp_field.after( timestamp.withtime(2,30,0,0) )
```

I would like to have a robust solution that will save me the hassle of changing the cutoff timestamp queries every few months. Can I add the timezone to the query statement itself? Is there any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling unsuccessfully with trying ot do it in the WHERE caluse or using a Pattern, I managed to solve the issue using a [Single-Row Function plugin][1].

I pass the plugin function the cutoff hour, timezone & event timezone and compute the cutoff hour in the event's timezone.

My query changed to:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM   my_table
WHERE  timestamp_field.after( timestamp.withtime(
       eventTZHour(2, 'UTC', 'Europe/Prague'), 30, 0, 0) )
```

I added the Java implementation in a class:

```java
public class EsperPlugins {
    public int eventTZHour(int hour, String eventTZ, String cutoffTZ) {
       // return tz calculations
    }
}
```

and finally registered the plugin in `esper.cfg.xml`:

```xml
<esper-configuration>
    <plugin-singlerow-function name="eventTZHour"
         function-class="EsperPlugins"
         function-method="eventTZHour"/>
</esper-configuration>
```

[1]: http://www.espertech.com/esper/release-5.2.0/esper-reference/html/extension.html#custom-singlerow-function from esper's docs

Answer (score 0):

It may help to add an event property to the event that represents UTC time i.e. normalize the event timestamp to UTC and use the normalized property instead. 
The query could also use a variable instead of the hardcoded numbers. Another option would perhaps be changing Esper source to take in a timezone for some func.s

Comment: The events' timestamp is in UTC. The problem is that the cutoff instant is timezone dependent.

Comment: Compute the cut-off instant from the event if the event carries the time zone?

Comment: No. I have a stream of events, and several queries to filter out the ones that are of interest. The queries have the cutoff time hard coded, but it does not include the timezone, so every 6 months, I have to load an updated query. I want to avoid that by using the timezone somehow in the query.

Comment: You could also use a variable and set a new variable value when there is a change.